# Why do we have to fill our buffer inside a while-true loop?

Tags: java, networking, udp, buffer

Below is my code from my UDP server and my question for you is:

Why does `Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0);` not work properly if this statement were to be placed outside the while-true loop?

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

            while (true) {
                Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0);
                try {
                    socket.receive(packet);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("[SERVER] Unable to receive packets from buffer");
                }

                InetAddress ip = packet.getAddress();
                int port = packet.getPort();
                String data = new String(packet.getData());
                
                if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("quit server")) {
                    socket.close();
                }
                // sending response back

                DatagramPacket pt = new DatagramPacket(packet.getData(), packet.getData().length, ip, port);

                try {
                    socket.send(pt);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("[SERVER] Unable to send packets to client.");
                }

            }

        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean, when you say it does not work, as in, what is your expectation and what actually happens? Reading this code what you have is a listener and the `Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0)` is intended to initialize your buffer with empty information. What does not work about it?

Comment: The thing is: it does work! However! If would place " Arrays.fill(buffer, (byte) 0) " outside the while(true) loop then it woudn't work, it just woudn't fill the buffer. I don't get that part.

Comment: It's basically a buffer reset. Otherwise presumably traces of data you received over the previous loop iteration remain in the buffer and lead to a corrupted package